# JSP java servlet keep get error in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i tried to make this work .

But still give me error

I still new in this

My .jsp file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Staff Page - Add Book</title>
    </head>

    <body>
                <center>
                    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Return Book Form.</h2>


                    <form name="uForm" method="get" action="addbookServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <table align="center" width="300px" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;border:1px solid #e5e5e5; padding:5px;">
                            <tr><td colspan=2 align="center" height="10px"></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Book ID</b></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="book_id" size="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Book Title</b></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="book_title" size="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Book Author</b></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="book_author" size="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Book Quantity</b></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="book_quantity" size="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Book Location</b></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="book_location" size="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Book Image</b></td>
                                <td><input type="file" name="book_image" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" size="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" class="g-button" value="Submit"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td colspan=2 align="center" height="10px"></td></tr>
                        </table>

                    </form>
                </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

My .java file

```
package caal;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import caal.DbConnection.*;

public class AddBook extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //response.setContentType("text/html");
       // PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection con = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client
       // Statement stmt;


        String book_id = request.getParameter("book_id");
        String book_title = request.getParameter("book_title");
        String book_author = request.getParameter("book_author");
        String book_quantity = request.getParameter("book_quantity");
        String book_location = request.getParameter("book_location");
        //String book_image = request.getParameter("book_image");
        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("book_image");
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            con = DbConnection.getConn();
            String query = "INSERT INTO booktable(bookId, bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookQuantity, bookLocation, bookimage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            System.out.println("query " + query);
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, book_id);
            statement.setString(2, book_title);
            statement.setString(3, book_author);
            statement.setString(4, book_quantity);
            statement.setString(5, book_location);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
                statement.setBlob(6, inputStream);
            }
            //stmt = con.createStatement();
            //stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

My web.xml become error . if i put like this

```
 <!-- SERVLET FOR ADD BOOK -->
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>addBookServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>caal.AddBook</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>addBookServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/addbookServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <multipart-config>
    <location>/tmp</location>
    <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

The error is

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [fpx] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 23; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'multipart-config'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":display-name, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":icon, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":distributable, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":context-param, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":filter, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":filter-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":listener, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":mime-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":welcome-file-list, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":error-page, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":jsp-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":security-constraint, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":login-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":security-role, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":env-entry, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":ejb-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":ejb-local-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":service-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":resource-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":resource-env-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-destination-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-destination, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":locale-encoding-mapping-list}' is expected.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I also have try using @MultipartConfig but it still not working . I need some help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web.xml, you must have correct and corresponding DOCTYPE and DTD/XSD setting, otherwise you may get xml invalidation error.

Try check your web.xml XSD setting refer [here](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xmlDTDAndXSD) and try again.

> *The XSD version is preferred since JSP 2.0 / Servlets 2.4 (eg: Tomcat 5.5). Note that the XML encoding can be specified as ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, or any other valid encoding in either version, and should match the actual encoding of your text file.*